# Does the golang.org/x/oauth2/google library support service to service authentication?

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I developped a Python backend service which connects to the Google Calendar API (v3), retrieves calendar entries and exposes them (they are retrieved by via an HTTP call). In order to do so, I use [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

When developping my application a few years ago, the module provided by Google was not yet ported to Python 3 and I went the JWT way ("HTTP/REST" in the documentation linked above).

I now would like to learn Go and start by porting this application.

The [Google Calendar API quickstart for Go](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/go) provides a full example, but it assumes that the authentication will include a consent screen from the user (3-legged oAuth). This is similar to the Python example, but there is also a Python version using the service to service approach.

**Is this service to service authentication funtionality available in the Go library?**

If it is not I will manually generate a JWT (as I do it now with the Python version of my code) but since I am just starting with Go, I would prefer using libraries as much as possible while I learn on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not setup to test this at the moment but I believe something like this should work:

package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    calendar "google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3"
)

func main() {
    cred, err := ioutil.ReadFile("service_account.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read JSON credentials config %v", err)
    }

    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(cred, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to obtain JWT conf %v", err)
    }

    client := conf.Client(context.Background())
    srv, err := calendar.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve calendar Client %v", err)
    }
  ...
}
```

The contents of `service_account.json` should be obtained from the service account configuration somehow, I'm not 100% sure about that part though.